# How to say "There's no more ice cream left" using the form "The ice cream is..."

Tags: grammar, synonyms

In my native language I'd say "the ice cream is finished", but that sounds weird in English.

The ice cream is over? Gone?

All of these sound incorrect.

Using a dictionary to translate the verb from my language gives me "come to an end". But no one says "The ice cream came to an end" either! :)

Comment: I would just say, 'the ice cream has all been eaten'

Comment: I see, thanks. So it's one of those examples where there's no direct translation.

Comment: "The ice cream is finished" sounds all too familiar to my (British) ears. [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/finished)]: << **finished**
 [adjective] (COMPLETED)
 
completed, final or completely used :
... 
UK The rebels' ammunition is almost finished and it is only a matter of time before they surrender. >>

Comment: @Alex As Edwin Ashworth pointed out, 'the ice cream is finished' would also work.

Comment: *The ice-cream is [**all**] **gone**!*

Comment: @YosefBaskin "Kaput" (slang) is not Italian originally, but German (Kaputt). It seems that "Caput" is something else, at least in BrE.

Comment: You have to wait until the ice cream is finished to eat it, otherwise it's just a goopy mess.

Comment: As for direct translations, assume that is the exception, not rule.

Comment: @FumbleFingers is correct. I think this is the best answer. To my ear, it sounds as though the "all" is required. If the ice cream is gone, that suggests some kind of vanishing. If it is all gone, then the natural idea is that it has been eaten.